# Switching forms with button click

Tags: javascript, html, css, button

I would like to change my form with a button click like so

http://postimg.org/image/ticav4jrb/

Even if someone could point me in the right direction that would be great I'm pretty new at this

Comment: use jquery UI and tabs.

Comment: [Is this direction OK?](http://jqueryui.com/tabs/) Not being a fan of One Direction, [here is an alternative direction](http://www.barelyfitz.com/projects/tabber/) (but this is just for comical effect, use the JQuery approach)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is the general principle without using jquery.

We create 2 `div`s and `float` them side by side, these will be our tabs, or course you can have more.

We create 2 more `div`s, these will be our pages, and we `position` them `absolute`ly below the tab `div`s and one over the other using `z-index`.

We add a `click` event listener to the 2 tab `div`s, and when clicked we reverse the `z-index` value of the 2 pages.

You can find plenty of [3rd party libraries/script/css](http://www.hongkiat.com/blog/50-nice-clean-css-tab-based-navigation-scripts/) out there.

CSS

```
#tab1 {
    width: 10em;
    height: 2em;
    float: left;
    background-color: green;
    cursor: pointer;
}
#tab2 {
    width: 10em;
    height: 2em;
    float: left;
    background-color: red;
    cursor: pointer;
}
#page1 {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    z-index: 1;
    position: absolute;
    top: 2em;
    background-color: green;
    clear:both;
}
#page2 {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    z-index: 0;
    position: absolute;
    top: 2em;
    background-color: red;
    clear:both;
}
```

HTML

```
<div id="tab1">Tab 1</div>
<div id="tab2">Tab 2</div>
<div id="page1">Some text in page 1</div>
<div id="page2">Some text in page 2</div>
```

Javascript

```
var tab1 = document.getElementById("tab1"),
    tab2 = document.getElementById("tab2"),
    page1 = document.getElementById("page1"),
    page2 = document.getElementById("page2");

tab1.addEventListener("click", function () {
    page1.style.zIndex = "1";
    page2.style.zIndex = "0";
});

tab2.addEventListener("click", function () {
    page1.style.zIndex = "0";
    page2.style.zIndex = "1";
});
```

On [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Xotic750/pS2gD/)